# My regular expression matches unexpected patterns

Tags: regex

would anyone know why is the second pattern displayed it should not match the regex...

```
$grep [[:digit:]{4}] file
99g66
9888
$
```

Comment: The answer is probably that you've written a character class containing digits, as well as `{` and `}`.  Hence, both the first lines match.  By the way, we can't read your question at all after your latest edit.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Because the englobing `[]` will escape your `{4}` part.

The correct way of achieving this is the following

### **[`[[:digit:]]{4}`](https://regex101.com/r/tVKPf3/1)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Your expression `[[:digit:]{4}]` is a [character set](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that matches either a digit, a `{`, or `}`. You probably meant `[[:digit:]]{4}`. Use that regular expression in extended mode with `grep -E` or `egrep` or escape the braces when using basic regular expression mode:

```
$ egrep '[[:digit:]]{4}' file

$ grep '[[:digit:]]\{4\}' file  # braces escaped
```

Comment: For the record, I upvote solid material :-)

Comment: it worked for me thanks @jspcal